# Use a colormap as a palette in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This is probably a misunderstanding how colormaps are different from palettes, but I'd like to use a colormap that is not available in seaborn for coloring my binned dataset. I tried using palettable and now cmocean in particular directly but will get a TypeError;

> 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object is not iterable

Using any of the palettes that are available in Seaborn will work just fine, but I need a palette that doesn't go to white as this adds a weird 'banding' to the plot.

I have a dataframe with 3 columns with numerical data, dimensions and added a bin column for the colors usage in the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import cmocean

cmap=cmocean.cm.balance
cpal=sns.color_palette(cmap,n_colors=64,desat=0.2)

plt.style.use("seaborn-dark")
ax = sns.stripplot(x='Data', y='Dimension', data=dfBalance, jitter=0.15, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.4, size=4, hue='bin', palette=cpal)
sns.despine()
ax.legend_.remove()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seaborn does not take a `Colormap` instance as input for `.color_palette`. [It takes](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html#seaborn.color_palette)

> name of matplotlib cmap, [...], or a list of colors in any format matplotlib accepts

Since cmocean registers its colormaps with matplotlib with a `"cmo."` prefix, you would do

```
import seaborn as sns
import cmocean

cpal = sns.color_palette("cmo.balance", n_colors=64, desat=0.2)
```

In case you have a custom colormap created yourself or from any other package, you might register it yourself.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.cm
import matplotlib.colors

cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["brown", "pink", "limegreen"])
matplotlib.cm.register_cmap("mycolormap", cmap)
cpal = sns.color_palette("mycolormap", n_colors=64, desat=0.2)
```

Comment: this seems to work, however the plot is now greyscaled somehow?

Comment: That's unfortunate, but nothing I can solve with the information at hand. Feel free to provide a [mcve] of the issue though.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the full code to generate the included plot

Comment: Supposedly you want to use `desat=1` instead of `desat=0` to see the colors?

Comment: doh! stupid me .. will edit the post back to initial state to avoid confusing for future reference ;) 
thx

Comment: Actually, I totally understand the reasoning you had. Full saturation should show the colors, completely desaturated colors would loose their color information. Setting saturation to 1 would be equivalent to desaturation =0. However seaborn uses a different reasoning somehow. Or the `de` in `desat` means something else. How knows.

Comment: The `register_cmap` function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.7 and will be removed. Use `matplotlib.colormaps.register(name)` instead.